# SQL - Get the latest event from table

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook, greatest-n-per-group

I got two tables.
A dealer table (id, name, etc.) and an event table (id, did(dealerid), eid(fb eventid), venue, etc.) where I save the dealerid, eventid, eventurl and date from facebook.

I can get all data with this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dealer as t_d INNER JOIN events AS t_e
ON t_d.id = t_e.did;
```

This works fine.

```
1   Laden Dortmund  Stra    12  45525   Dortmund    DE  www.google.de   0201-123456 laden@dortmund.de   300 400 1   1   416364098428245 https://www.facebook.com/events/416364098428245/    2013-01-28
2   Laden Unna  Wurststr.   123 45130   Unna    DE  www.bing.de 0222-11223344   laden@unna.de   400 276 2   2   145457548940302 https://www.facebook.com/events/145457548940302/    2013-03-08
2   Laden Unna  Wurststr.   123 45130   Unna    DE  www.bing.de 0222-11223344   laden@unna.de   400 276 3   2   405092472902921 https://www.facebook.com/events/405092472902921/    2013-04-26
```

As you can see, I get two rows for the dealer id 2, because there are two events listed.
How can I get the event, which is the closest to this date (today).

Later, there will be like 20 Dealer and for each one at least 3-4 events.

A hint would be nice, thank you!

**UPDATE:**
This is the solution!

```
SELECT  t_d.*, t_e.*, DATE_FORMAT(t_e.date,'%d.%m.%Y') as date
    FROM    dealer as t_d
    INNER JOIN events AS t_e
        ON t_d.id = t_e.did
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  did, MIN(date) minDate
        FROM    events
        GROUP BY did
    ) e ON  t_e.did = e.did AND
            t_e.date = e.minDate
```

But is it somehow possible to display ALL dealers, even if no event exists for the dealer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  t_d.*, t_e.*
FROM    dealer as t_d 
        INNER JOIN events AS t_e
            ON t_d.id = t_e.did
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  did, MAX(date) maxDate
            FROM    events
            GROUP BY did
        ) e ON  t_e.did = e.did AND
                t_e.date = e.maxDate
```

Comment: This goes in the right direction but I gives me farthest, not the closest. But MIN(date) did it! Thanks!

Comment: Is it somehow possible to display all dealers, even if no event exists?

Comment: Sure; change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` both places.

Comment: Ok, thats a step forward, but now I get dealers twice or three times and the event to it.
I just need the nearerst event for the specific dealer. Is this also possible?